# set values by file names in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi I want to set value `InFile` for all text files in a directory which means that I want the batch file to load and do the command for all of the text files in the  directory one by one.

Normally I just copy the command how many times files are then I replace `Infile` with every file name. By this code I get the file names and then I replace them.

```
cd /d "dir"
dir /a /b /-p /o:gen >names.txt
```

and here's the example of a command.

```
@Echo OFF
REM Set These Variables
SET "InFile=123.txt"
SET "OutFile=NowLoad.txt"
SET "Replace=KK"
SET "ReplaceWith=JJ"

REM Get Total Lines Number [including empty lines]
FOR /F %%A IN ('TYPE "%InFile%"^|find /v /c ""') DO SET "Till=%%A"

REM Create The OutFile with changes
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
<"!InFile!" (
  FOR /L %%a IN (1 1 0) DO SET /p "="
  FOR /L %%A IN (1 1 %Till%) DO (
    SET "line="
    SET /P "line="
    IF "!line!x" == "x" ( Echo.
   ) ELSE ( Echo !line:%Replace%=%ReplaceWith%!)
  )
)>>"%OutFile%"

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: I don't think your command `dir /a /b /-p o:gen` is correct

Comment: You must read how to ask question. Because I got lost after reading "I want to set value InFile to all of the text files in a dir"

Comment: Where `names.txt` is used in your batch?

Comment: @Paul: I think the command could perhaps be written shorter but there are no real errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way...

Your script is DOIT.bat.

Change DOIT.bat to use a command line parameter for the filename you want to process.

```
@Echo OFF
REM Set These Variables
SET "InFile=%~1"
SET "OutFile=NowLoad.txt"
...
```

Create another file named CALLIT.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`dir /b *.txt`) DO (
    CALL DOIT.bat "%%~f"
)
```

Running CALLIT.bat will process every .txt file in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

no need to count the lines, just process every line:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  ( for /f "delims=" %%A in (%%f) do (
      set line=%%A
      set line=!line:%Replace%=%ReplaceWith%!
      echo(!line!
    )
  )>%%~nf.out
)
```

Note: the `(` after `echo` handles empty lines (an empty line is written with no "echo is off" if `!line!` is empty)

**edited** to process all .txt files in the Folder. Because a fixed %oufile% would overwrite the same outfile with every processed infile, I changed it to a new Extension: `<SameNameAsInputFile>.out`

Comment: Thank you but it was only an example I want to set the file names to the values it was just an example. :)

Comment: @kmthrongkmthrongi  If you don't give accurate examples then you will often not get workable solutions.  This is a programming language and needs specific details to write exact code.

Comment: @foxidrive agree to you but this time I explained everything so obvious and nothing's wrong with the example I mean i'm trying to solve it as setting values every time and running the script but the dude Stephan solved it in another way I just said TNX but I need it to be in that method I've written (by setting values).

Comment: @Stephan sorry and tnx I just saw the edit now I tried that it doesn't do anything special just replaces KK with JJ I could do that by my code.my question was something else I wanted to do it for all of the text files in the folder but your code just works with %INfile% what does your code do can you explain a bit cause I couldn't do anything with that tnx.

Comment: @Paul I'm exactly talking about that names.txt I can't use it so as I said I just copy the command how many files are for example I have 3 txt file in a folder so I copy the code and paste it 3 times then for each command I use the names in names.txt and replace %Infile% in each command I want to use a batch file to do it for me in a second cause it takes too much time by my crazy method.

Comment: @kmthrongkmthrongi see my edit. By the way: your explanation obviously wasn't that obvious...

Comment: Sorry I came here a bit late ok that works great with for/f command what for the other kinds for example I want to use copy /b each.txtfile to example.txt
?

Comment: you know, what happens, if you copy several files to the same filename? But if you insist: just replace `>%%~nf.out` with `>example.txt` or `>>example.txt`

Comment: Tnx but I didn't mean that I mean combine every text file like 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt each one with a file like h.txt so by that i can add a part of text to each file so if 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt are blank we'll have h.txt content in every file after doing the command.

Comment: Adding fixed text to the end of the outputfiles? Easy: just add `type h.txt>>%%~nf.out` before the last paranthese.